# Activate DEBUG only for CAS (jasig) classes on Tomcat 7

Tags: debugging, logging, tomcat7, cas

I would like to activate the DEBUG logs only for CAS classes in a Tomcat 7 where I deployed [`cas.war`](http://www.jasig.org/cas) webapp.

So I followed the [Tomcat 7 documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html) about logging and added this in my `/etc/tomcat7/logging.properties` file :

```
...
org.apache.catalina.level=FINEST
...
org.jasig.cas.level = ALL
```

But then I have all the logs of the Tomcat 7 itself (ClassLoader debug stuffs for example), and it seems I still don't have the DEBUG log for CAS...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, no need to modify Tomcat 7 `logging.properties` file.

You have to edit `WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml` of the `cas.war` and modify that line :

```
<logger name="org.jasig" additivity="true">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="cas" />
</logger>
```